# How do I get the full list of numbers (in stead of only the last line)?

Tags: python

I need to extract a list of numbers from a .txt file so that I can compute the average price. The file looks like this:

```
Cola__________________3.5 2.9 3.6

Fanta_________________3.4 2.3 3.2

Pepsi_________________3.5 2.9 3.4
```

I came up with this code:

```
def get_numbers(file):
    infile = open('costs.txt', 'r')
    numbers = []
    for lines in infile:
        numbers = (lines[22:])
    infile.close()
    return numbers
```

However, this shows only the last row of prices. I need to get the prices of all the rows so that the average price per product can be computed.

I am new to Python and struggling to get this right for hours already. Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: `numbers.append(lines[22:])`?

Comment: You are not adding items to your array - you're overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

In this line you are writing over the numbers variable

```
numbers = (lines[22:])
```

Change it to:

```
numbers.append(lines[22:])
```

Answer (score 0):

A more flexible way:

```
import re

with open('costs.txt', 'r') as f:
    pat = re.compile(r'^([A-Z][^_]+)_*(\d+.+\d+$)')
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            product, numbers = pat.search(line).groups()
            numbers = numbers.split()
            print('Product: {}. Avg: {:.2f}'
                  .format(product, sum(map(float, numbers)) / len(numbers)))
```

Sample output:

```
Product: Cola. Avg: 3.33
Product: Fanta. Avg: 2.97
Product: Pepsi. Avg: 3.27
```